# Can the covariance of "y" and "beta1" be unequal to 0 in a simple linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear-model, covariance

For a simple linear regression model $y = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x +\epsilon$, where $\hat\beta_{0}$ and $\hat\beta_{1}$ are estimates of $\beta_{0}$ and $\beta_{1}$. Then can we prove that, $$cov( y,\hat{\beta_{1}})\neq 0$$

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "$y$" in your question.  If it's a (scalar) random variable, then how is it associated with the data that produced the estimate $\hat\beta_1$?  And if it refers to the $n$ responses in the data, then please explain what you mean by the covariance between this $n$-vector and the scalar $\hat\beta_1$.

Comment: The proof is rather easy if we assume that the $X$ are non-stochastic, because then we have $Cov(Y,\hat{\beta})=Cov(Y,(X'X)^{-1}X'Y)=Var(Y)X(X'X)^{-1}$